# To edit the values of dynamically added input fields

Tags: typescript, angular-material, angular6

**SCENARIO :**

- I have an component called `demo` which is  having  dropdown for `Employee type` and an input field for `Employee Id`.
- After clicking **+** Icon i am adding these two fields `(i,e Employee Type & Id)` dynamically as shown below:

[image]

- I am able **add** & **delete** these dynamically added values`(i,e Employee Type & Id)`.Means on clicking **cancel icon ( X )** i am able to **delete** the added values.

**EXPECTED RESULT :**

> I want to edit the added values (i,e EMployee Type & Id)` on clicking Edit ( i,e pen icon)

Means on clicking `pen icon` again i should return back to the field to edit the values as shwown below:

[image]

Stackblitz **[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-ccv3yk?file=app/demo/demo.component.ts)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-edvuel?file=app/demo/demo.component.ts) stackblitz. When the user clicks the edit icon, the values will be editable in the input fields, when he clicks the add button the fields will be cleared and the object is updated (not added again).

**demo.component.ts**

```
addFieldValue() {
  // only add object if it is a new one
  if (this.fieldArray.indexOf(this.newAttribute) === -1) {
    this.fieldArray.push(this.newAttribute)
  }    

  this.newAttribute = {};
  console.log(this.fieldArray);
}          

editFieldValue(index) {
 this.newAttribute = this.fieldArray[index];
}
```

**demo.componentht**

```
<td (click)="editFieldValue(i)">
  <i class="material-icons">
    create
  </i>
</td>
```